# Reputation system: weighted points vs unweighted points?

Tags: html, web-services, web, system, recommendation-engine

I am developing one small reputation system, and I faced one problem.

So, in my example I want to create a website for pictures with 4 different types of user; let's call them: *amateur*, *good*, *very good*, *professional*.

Each user can upload a picture and this picture can get rated by other users. When the user reaches certain number of points, he passes to the next level 
(e.g. if he was amateur, he becames good).

---

*Now my question is:* **How should I develop this reputation system?**

Should I include weighted points or unweighted?

E.g. if *professional user* gives 5 stars to a *amateur user* pic, should this bring more points then when a *good user* gives 5 stars to an *amateur user* pic?
Also for negative points.

Which path should I choose? How to choose the right solution?

Is there some name for this kind of "problems" so I can read about it?

Could you address me on what should I pay attention with both solutions and what are the pro and cons?

Thank you

PREVIOUSLY READ:
I read about SO pointing system, precisely this:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57278/if-a-user-has-good-rep-on-a-particular-tag-shouldnt-his-votes-on-that-tag-weig

This answer made me think about. Which way should I choose?

Answer (score 2):

This is a tremendously difficult question to answer, without knowing the specifics of a use case. Is there a reason to believe that those who have reached higher levels are more authoritative in delivering ratings to others? It may be the case. It is notable, however, that you are almost by definition creating a system which will lead to conformity - that may or may not be what you are looking to do.

There are some interesting implementation questions, if you decide to go ahead with such a system. Does the relative ranking of two individuals matter, or just the one who is rating? (i.e. if you are "good" and I am "very good", should my vote on your image be the same as if you are "amateur" and I am "very good"? or should it hold less weight in the first case since we are presumably closer individuals?)

If I rate someone when I am very good, and then later I cross the threshold into professional, does my rating get scaled by the "very good" or does it later get updated when I update?

If I am an individual who currently has no ratings by anyone, and a Professional individual rates me as Professional, should that count for more or less than if I am someone who has been called an Amateur by 100s of Amateurs, and then a single Professional rates me as a Professional? In other words, how does the variance of ratings get reconciled with the variance of weightings?

So, in some type of summary: If there is reason to believe that those who rank more highly will be better judges of how others rank, **and** you do not mind uniformity of the highly ranked individuals, then perhaps a weighted ranking system may work.

If you are looking to implement a weighted ranking system, then you need to decide exactly what matters. Is it the relative weights? Is it the explicit weights?

---

My recommendation would be to think about specific scenarios. Enumerating how this should work specifically may help you generalize a solution.

As some readings of interest:

- https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/trueskill-ranking-system/
- https://en.chessbase.com/post/the-sonas-rating-formula-better-than-elo-

Answer (score 1):

The reputation of a voter should almost certainly influence the weight of her vote and how much it affects the votee's reputation, as long as you believe that a person's reputation directly correlates with her ability to judge the reputation of others.

Take a look at the [Elo rating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system) and its peers (with [R implementation here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PlayerRatings/index.html)). Player ratings -- analogous to your reputation calculations -- depend on their opponents' ratings, not just a simple win/loss incrementing.